# Magento: Core sends welcome mail after customer is saved

Tags: email, magento, admin, backend

I noticed the following bug:

When I add an address to a customer using the admin backend, or if I change an address and i save the customer, the Magento Costumer AccountController sends a standard email to the updated customer. The email template used is the template for the customer event "confirmed". This always happens when I update the customer.

Had someone the same problem or a solution for this? I can't understand why magento sends an email for this event...

Answer (score 1):

Class: `Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController` extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`

Methode: `saveAction()`

Solution: It's a core bug from older versions. The condition for sending a mail after saving a customer uses `isset($sendPassToEmail)`. But if you notice, the `sendPassToEmail` variable is always set and has the values true or false. Because of the `isset()` the condition is always true and an email will be send every time a customer is saved.

...

```
            $sendPassToEmail = false;
            // force new customer active
            if ($isNewCustomer) {
                $customer->setPassword($data['account']['password']);
                $customer->setForceConfirmed(true);
                if ($customer->getPassword() == 'auto') {
                    $sendPassToEmail = true;
                    $customer->setPassword($customer->generatePassword());
                }
            }

            Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_customer_prepare_save', array(
                'customer'  => $customer,
                'request'   => $this->getRequest()
            ));

            $customer->save();

            // send welcome email
            if ($customer->getWebsiteId() && (!empty($data['account']['sendemail']) || isset($sendPassToEmail))) {
                $storeId = $customer->getSendemailStoreId();
                if ($isNewCustomer) {
                    $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('registered', '', $storeId);
                }
                // confirm not confirmed customer
                else if ((!$customer->getConfirmation())) {
                    $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmed', '', $storeId);
                }
            }
```